Problema con 'La conversión especificada no es válida' en Windows Forms c# con controles de DevExpress 22.2.3
Estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio en Visual Studio 22 con controles de DevExpress 22.2.3 y se esta desarrollando para una maquina con Windows 7.
Lo que pasa es que al ejecutar la aplicación me sale un error de  'La conversión especificada no es válida'
¿Alguien sabe cual puede ser el detalle si me faltan ensamblados o si es un problema de compatibilidad?


Ese error debe especificar mucho mejor cual es el problema...
